# how to exclude hours,minutes,seconds in oracle sql group by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

[image]

As in above image EX:i am getting 3 records for `28-NOV-2019`, Actual  requirement is 1 record should come for `28-NOV-2019` with total as 9. how to write sql query in oracle.

```
select UPD_DTIME, count(*) as total 
from xyz_T   
group by UPD_DTIME 
order by UPD_DTIME desc;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see images, but - from what you described, `TRUNC` is what you're looking for:

```
  SELECT TRUNC (UPD_DTIME) upd_time, 
         COUNT (*) AS total
    FROM xyz_T
GROUP BY TRUNC (UPD_DTIME)
ORDER BY TRUNC (UPD_DTIME) DESC;
```